# The @Aspect don't work for a dynamic bean register by "registerBeanDefinition"

Tags: spring-boot

I register a bean using "registerBeanDefinition", but the aspect don't work on this bean.

```
/* tool class */
@Component
public class SpringBeanUtil {
    public <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz){
        BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(clazz);
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = 
        (DefaultListableBeanFactory)configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();

        beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.getName(), builder.getRawBeanDefinition());

        Object bean = configurableApplicationContext.getBean(clazz.getName());
        return (T) bean;
}

/* my class */
public class ResourceHandle{
    public ResourceHandle() {}

    @WorkFlow
    public void create(Resource rc) {
        System.out.println("ResourceHandle:create:{}.", rc)
        return;
    }
}

/* annotation class */
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface WorkFlow {
    String name() default "";
}


/* aspcet class */
@Component
@Aspect
public class WorkFlowAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.workflow.WorkFlow)")
    public void cutAction() {
    }

    @Around(value = "@annotation(com.workflow.WorkFlow)")
    public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Resource retResource = null;
        retResource = (Resource)joinPoint.proceed();
        return retResource;
    }
}
```

I invoke code like this,

```
ResourceHandle handle = SpringBeanUtil.getBean(ResourceHandle.class);
handle.create(rc);
```

the @Aspect "doAround" don't work.But when i change the "ResourceHandle class" to:

```
/* my class */
@Component
public class ResourceHandle{
    public ResourceHandle() {}

    @WorkFlow
    public void create(Resource rc) {
        System.out.println("ResourceHandle:create:{}.", rc)
        return;
    }
}
```

invoke code like this,

```
@Autowired
ResourceHandle handle;
........
handle.create(rc);
```

the @Aspect "doAround" work.But i want to create bean myself.How can i do it?